# Number of permutations with constraint

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Let $N \geq 1$ and $I_N:=\{1,...,N\}$. Let $j \in I_{N}$ be fixed. I can decompose the set $I_{n}$ into $I_{N-j} = \{1,...,N-j\}$ and $I_{N-j}^{c} = \{N-j+1,...,N\}$. I am stuck at this problem for a while now. How do I find the number of permutations $\sigma$ such that for every $i \in I_{N-j}^{c}$ one has $\sigma(i) \not\in I_{N-j}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $i$ in $I_{N-j}^c$ is sent by $\sigma$ into $I_{N-j}^c$ itself. This means that $\sigma(I_{N-j}^c)=I_{N-j}^c$. Thus, being a permutation a bijection, $\sigma(I_{N-j})=I_{N-j}$.

Therefore, $sigma$ is basically given by a permutation $\sigma_1$ on $I_{N-j}$ and a permutation $\sigma_2$ on $I_{N-j}^c$.

The permutations on $I_{N-j}$ are $(N-j)!$, while those on $I_{N-j}^c$ are $j!$. Thus, the total number of permutations you are looking for is:
$$(N-j)!\cdot j! \ \ \ .$$